# Ajax Not Posting Data to Backend MVVM C#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I am trying to post data from the front end HTML page to the backend code C# in a MVVM, I will either get a 404 or 400 error while making a lot of testing scenarios (usually the path).

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ReportModel/DepAct',
    data: JSON.stringify({ prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2' }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Data sent to backend!');
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Data was not sent to backend!');
    }
});
```

And this is the backend:

```
public ActionResult DepAct(List<DepTB> selectedDep)
{
    // Process data as needed
    return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
}
```

I tried changing the path, data type, give different kinds of data in the front end and in the backend I tried to add different methods with different parameters like just a string, list based on a class etc.

Update 1:

Modified the code to return the same data type and tested one of the answers but no luck

Javascript

```
var selectedDep = [{ prop1: "value1", prop2: "value2" }];
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Report/DepAct',
                data: JSON.stringify(selectedDep),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Data sent to backend!');
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('Data was not sent to backend!');
                }
            });
```

Someone requested for the class as well

```
public class DepTB1
    {
        public string prop1 { get; set; }
        public string prop2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Method

```
public ActionResult DepAct([FromBody] List<DepTB1> selectedDep)
        {
            // Process data as needed
            return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
        }
```

Comment: Could you please include `List<DepTB>` class as well in order to inspect that.

Comment: first endpoint seems to expect array/list and you are sending object

Comment: I think you have to include `/` at the front of the url. `/ReportModel/DepAct`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Included

Comment: @Selvin You are right but the error persists

Comment: @djolf Tried it but does not seem to be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working after adding OnPost in front of the method's name in the class

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult OnPostDepAct([FromBody] List<DepTB1> selectedDep)
        {
            // Process data as needed
            return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
        }
```

And using the following kind or URL in the Javascript

```
var selectedDep = [{ prop1: "value1", prop2: "value2" }];
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Reports/Report?handler=DepAct',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                data: selectedDep,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Data sent to backend!');
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('Data was not sent to backend!');
                }
            });
```

Thanks all for trying!

Answer (score 0):

> I tried changing the path, data type, give different kinds of data in
> the front end and in the backend I tried to add different methods with
> different parameters like just a string, list based on a class etc.

Your controller action parameter expecting list but you are sending single object which mismatched with method signature. Another important issue is you are missing [FromBody]  because by default ajax request type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but you are sending json data.

Assuming you have following class:

Model:

```
public class DepTB
    {
        public string prop1 { get; set; }
        public string prop2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Modify Ajax code:

```
var selectedDep = [{ prop1: "value1", prop2: "value2" }];


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/ReportModel',
                data: JSON.stringify(selectedDep),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Data sent to backend!');
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('Data was not sent to backend!');
                }
            });
```

**Note:** This would also be correct `JSON.stringify([{ prop1: "value1", prop2: "value2" }])`

Add [FromBody] In Controller:

```
public ActionResult OnPost([FromBody] List<DepTB> selectedDep)
        {
            // Process data as needed
            return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
        }
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** You can get more details here in [Jquery Official Document](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Update:

Based on your shared link and description, it appeared that, you are using razor page. While sending ajax request within razor page it requires addition `XSRF-TOKEN` in header, you could add following code snippet within your ajax request:

**Include XSRF-TOKEN in header:**

```
headers: {
          RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
         }
```

**You can ignore antiforgery token:**

You even can ignore forgery token by using `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` before your razor page as following:

**Page Model:**

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public class ReportModel : PageModel
{
    public ActionResult OnPost([FromBody] List<DepTB> selectedDep)
        {
            // Process data as needed
            return new JsonResult(new { success = true });
        }
}
```

**Ajax:**

```
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/ReportModel',
                data: JSON.stringify([{ prop1: "value1", prop2: "value2" }]),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                headers: {
                    RequestVerificationToken:
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Data sent to backend!');
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('Data was not sent to backend!');
                }
            });
```

Ouput:

[image]

Comment: I copied and pasted the code you just shared but it keeps throwing the same error... The class, method and javascript code exactly as yours. I don't understand what is going wrong

Comment: Include your full url instead of `'/ReportModel/DepAct'` for example, https://localhost:44307/controller/action`

Comment: So what actually happened is that when I put the full URL starting with "localhost:xxxx...." it will reject my request because of CORS standards (the link is unsafe), I thought at least it finds the path but after a while I placed the same link starting with "https://...." the request is not rejected but the previous error persists also I tried put a purposely wrong link without the https and its directly rejected meaning that the path was not recognised all along.

Comment: https://youtu.be/sn7dIMCAwa4 Please check it out, I recorded the error and everything

Comment: You are using razor page but you haven't mensioned it anywhere. For razor page you should pass additional `XSRF-TOKEN` within header or you should ingnore it in page model using `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` attribute before your razor page class. Do it and it will resolve your issue. In addition, while asking question, please include necessary information what kind of application you are using and its version along with error details which would help contibutor to check the root cause. Thus, check th updated part in my answer.

Comment: I am sorry about that. I tried your solution and it is still giving out the same error. It can't find the path? why?

Comment: Alright, rename postMethod name to `OnPost` instead of `DepAct` and try, razor routing need to configure otherwise. By default razor page treated `OnPost` or cannot find otherwise. See the updated answer.